# Difference between WCAG 2.5.2 pointer cancellation and 3.3.4 Error prevention

Tags: accessibility

I want to know the difference between wcag 2.5.2 pointer cancellation and 3.3.4 error prevention.
Both success criteria is saying same about there should be a confirmation before final submission
confirmation also refers to pointer cancellation - undo.

Answer (score 0):

While both WCAG 2.5.2 and 3.3.4 success criteria talk about confirmation and undo, there are some differences between them.

WCAG 2.5.2 Pointer Cancellation is focused on making sure that users have a way to cancel any pointer actions, such as clicking or tapping, before they take effect. This is important for users who may accidentally trigger an action and need a way to undo it. For example, a user may accidentally click a "Submit" button on a form, and WCAG 2.5.2 requires that there be a way to cancel that action and return to the previous state.

On the other hand, WCAG 3.3.4 Error Prevention is focused on making sure that users don't make errors in the first place. This success criterion requires that any legal, financial, or data-related actions that have irreversible consequences have a confirmation step before they are carried out. For example, if a user is about to delete a file or submit a form that will result in a financial transaction, they should be prompted to confirm that they really want to carry out that action before it is finalized. This helps prevent errors and ensures that users have a chance to review and confirm their actions before proceeding.